# Воспроизведение звука на Rust

Tags: аудио, rust

Хочу написать генератор морзе(может сетевой) на расте, дабы получше узнать язык. Но никак не могу найти способ воспроизвести какой-либо звук, желательно с настройкой частоты волны. Не знаете способ воспроизвести звук в rust?

Comment: в гиттере посоветовали посмотреть на rust-jack, https://github.com/tomaka/cpal и https://github.com/RustAudio/rust-portaudio